# How to run more then one program through a service (/etc/init/*.conf) file

Tags: 12.04, upstart, services

My service, an executable called /opt/mcp/rpe, requires that a second executable is also running, called /opt/mcp/McpVp.

In my conf file: /etc/init/mcp.conf I have:

```
description "Run MCP"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
        # Start the RPE application
        /opt/mcp/rpe -d f -c /opt/mcp
        # Start the McpVp application
        /opt/mcp/McpVp &> /var/tmp/mcp.log
end script
```

When I run this using: `sudo start mcp` I see that the rpe executable starts but the McpVp does not.
I also try to run both in background mode, this also does not seem to work, and what is worse, when I try to stop the script it can't find the "instance" - I guess because it is lost in the background.

So, is there a way to run 2 (or more) processes, such that it works with the start and stop command? (i.e. `sudo start mcp` and `sudo stop mcp`)

I know there are other ways to resolve this issue, but I specifically want to know if I can do this using the .conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do relatively easily is split the config into 2 configs of one executable with a
dependency between them.  Then when you `start mcp`, it automatically starts mcp2 as well, and when you `stop mcp`, it stops mcp2 as well.  Here's the files:

```
#----/etc/init/mcp.conf
description "Run MCP"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
# Start the RPE application
exec /opt/mcp/rpe -d f -c /opt/mcp
```

and

```
#----/etc/init/mcp2.conf
description "Run MCP 2"
start on starting mcp
stop on stopped mcp
# Start the McpVp application
exec /opt/mcp/McpVp &> /var/tmp/mcp.log
```